# Is it possible to purchase a non-recurring credit on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

My birthday is coming up and my parents asked me what I would like for a present.

I said "App Engine CPU hours".

But after looking at the billing options, I can't find a way for them to make a one-time credit to my account. The only option seems to be an authorization of a maximum billing amount for a particular time frame.

Is it not possible to give someone App Engine resources as a one-time gift?

Comment: Interesting mix of upvotes to question and votes to close.... Questions about service pricing are considering off-topic on SO. I think your question is best suited to the [appengine group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine) where the concept of "top up credit" has been voiced before, but is not currently an option.

Comment: I *think* App Engine is on topic on Webmasters. If not, I'm sure I'll hear about it soon...

Comment: @mmyers 10 questions on it here already, so it won't be lonely.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible, however, you aren't charged for usage below the free quotas.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to do this, unfortunately. All you can do is add your parents as a billing administrator of the account, have them enable the account for billing, and disable it again once you've spent the prescribed amount.